# Element-ui table: set label color

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I want the whole element-ui table's text to be black. I could achieve this in rows, using the `style` attribute:

```html
<el-table-column width="400" label="Product Name" prop="product.name"></el-table-column>
```

but that doesn't work for the table itself - the labels' colour doesn't seem to change:

[image: Screenshot]

I want the fields `Quantity` and `Price` to be black. Is there any way to get the expected result?

P.S: I don't want to customize the element-UI theme, but change the colour on one page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element UI tables have the `.el-table` class (and the header is in `<thead>`), so you could style it in CSS like this:

```css
.el-table {
  color: black;
}
.el-table thead {
  color: black;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KKVEPow)

Comment: It works in the included demo above, so I'm guessing your usage is somehow diifferent. Can you modify the demo above to match your use case?

Comment: my code is the same with the demo, but... it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. It will be difficult for anyone to help you if the problem can't be reproduced. Do you have a GitHub link perhaps?

Comment: wait... solved! The problem was in an unclosed tag, but I think this shouldn't affect the color.

Comment: Malformed HTML would prevent CSS selection